# как реализовать lowpassFilter для гироскопа

Tags: unity3d

Здравствуйте, я хочу повесить на гироскоп низкочастотный фильтр, чтобы он не так дрейфовал. Но на выходе с фильтра я получаю `NaN`. Я не могу понять почему это происходит.

Вот делал как тут : http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Low_Pass_Filter

Вот мой код:

```
 private Quaternion filteredQuarternion;
 float lowPassFactor = 0.5f;
 bool init = true;


 void Update() {
        Quaternion cameraRotation = new Quaternion(Input.gyro.attitude.x, Input.gyro.attitude.y, -Input.gyro.attitude.z, -Input.gyro.attitude.w);
        filteredQuarternion = lowPassFilterQuaternion(filteredQuarternion, cameraRotation, lowPassFactor , init);
        init = false;               
        this.transform.localRotation = filteredQuarternion;
    }


    Quaternion lowPassFilterQuaternion(Quaternion intermediateValue, Quaternion targetValue, float factor, bool init)  {        
        if (init){
            intermediateValue = targetValue;
        }
        intermediateValue = Quaternion.Lerp(intermediateValue, targetValue, factor);
        return intermediateValue;
    }
```

Но у меня на выходе, то есть все поля объекта `filteredQuarternion` равны `NaN`.

Помогите пожалуйста, что я делаю нет так? Может быть я что-то неправильно понял или упустил.

Answer (score 1):

```
Вот рабочий вариант:
float lowPassFactor = 0.8f;
bool init = true;
GameObject _cameraContainer;
Transform _cameraTransform;

private void Awake()
{
    _cameraTransform = Camera.main.GetComponent<Transform>();
    _cameraContainer = new GameObject();
    _cameraContainer.transform.position = _cameraTransform.position;
    _cameraTransform.SetParent(_cameraContainer.transform);
    _cameraContainer.transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(90f, 90f, 0f);
}
void Update() 
{
    _cameraTransform.localRotation = lowPassFilterQuaternion(_cameraTransform.localRotation, GyroToUnity(Input.gyro.attitude), lowPassFactor , init);
    init = false;               
}

Quaternion lowPassFilterQuaternion(Quaternion intermediateValue, Quaternion targetValue, float factor, bool init)
{ 
    //intermediateValue needs to be initialized at the first usage.
    if(init)
    {       
        intermediateValue = targetValue;
    }

    intermediateValue = Quaternion.Lerp(intermediateValue, targetValue, factor);
    return intermediateValue;
}

private static Quaternion GyroToUnity(Quaternion q)
{
    return new Quaternion(q.x, q.y, -q.z, -q.w);
}
```